# What is the relative size of the radical of an ABC-triple relative to the number of primes up to its largest element?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, divisors-multiples

Write $\bf N$ for the set of natural numbers, and $P$ for the set of primes. For $x$ in $\bf N$ let $p(x)$ be the product of the primes dividing $x$ (that is, the "radical" of $x$). Also write $\#(x)$ for the number of primes up to $x$. Let $S$ be the set of triples $(x,a,b)$ of naturals with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $x=a+b$. For $s=(x,a,b)$ in $S$, let $f(s)=\#(x)/(p(x)p(a)p(b))$. What is $\limsup_{s{\rm\ in\ }S}f(s)$?

Answer (score 2):

In more classical notation you seem to ask for 
$\frac{\pi(c)}{\operatorname{rad}(abc)}$
for an ABC-triple $c= a+ b$.

By results of van Frankenhuysen one has infinitely many triples 
such that 
$$\log c \ge  \log \operatorname{rad}(abc)  + k \sqrt{\log  c / \log \log c}  $$
for some positive $k$.

Written differently 
$$ \frac{c}{\operatorname{rad}(abc)}    \ge \exp(  k \sqrt{\log  c / \log \log c} ) $$

Now $\pi(c) \sim c/ \log c $, so for sufficiently large $c$

$$ \frac{\pi(c)}{\operatorname{rad}(abc)}    \ge k'\frac{\exp(  k \sqrt{\log  c / \log \log c} )}{\log c} $$
for some positive $k'$.

The right-hand side tends to infinity as $c$ tends to infinity, and so the limsup you ask about is infinite.

*Machiel van Frankenhuysen*, [**A lower bound in the $abc$ conjecture**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jnth.1999.2484), *J. Number Theory* **82** (2000), no. 1, 91--95.